# Execute HelloDate from Thinking in Java

Tags: java

**Ubuntu 18.04**

I've downloaded examples for "Thinking in Java". Unzipped them. Now I have to execute HelloDate.

```
.
├── operators
│   ├── HelloDate.class
│   ├── HelloDate.java
```

The code:

```
//: operators/HelloDate.java
import java.util.*;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

public class HelloDate {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    print("Hello, it's: ");
    print(new Date());
  }
} /* Output: (55% match)
Hello, it's:
Wed Oct 05 14:39:05 MDT 2005
*///:~
```

I compiled it like this:

```
michael@michael:~/Downloads/thinking_in_java/TIJ4-code-master/examples$ javac operators/HelloDate.java
```

The compilation was successful, as we can see.

Then:

```
michael@michael:~/Downloads/thinking_in_java/TIJ4-code-master/examples$ java operators.HelloDate 
Error: Could not find or load main class operators.HelloDate
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloDate (wrong name: operators/HelloDate)
```

Could you help me with this problem. First to understand it, secondly - to solve.

Answer (score 0):

When you download some ready examples like this from any tutorial, it will be better if you use any Java IDE's like Eclipse, Spring Tool Suite or IntelliJ IDEA and import the project there.

If you still need to execute from command line, all you need to do is, remove the "package" name, which will be in the first line.
Or as @Sebastian said, you can also try executing from "operators" sub directory.

```
javac operators/HelloDate.java
java HelloDate
```

And if that file happens to contain any other dependency classes/libraries (jar files), then you need to do all the circus of adding them into classpath and execute, as shown in this [tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-classpath/).
Eg:

```
$ javac –classpath C:\dependency\framework.jar HelloDate.Java
$ java –classpath C:\dependency\framework.jar HelloDate
```

Comment: No it is not better. First of all, this example is not for using with IDE because packages have not been introduced so far.

Comment: You are right, for this example it's not required. Going forward, when you explore more, you will not have time to do these basic things repetitively for all the demo programs. But command line always wins. Universal solutions can be found there. Even I'm a terminal loving guy.